# CLI Dir won't show folders with custom ico.file in folder

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I name my work folders `clientname.uniquenumber` and when I have a new job I use sort via `DIR /oe` to check that I don't duplicate numbers ([superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/571465/how-to-sort-folders-by-last-characters-of-folder-name-in-windows-7) reference for that).

I've started using [RainbowFolders](http://www.english.aionel.net/) to sort folders visually (by colour) so I can quickly sort active jobs from warm leads, completed jobs etc, and it works great. Rainbow folders creates a custom .ico file and places it in the selected folder.

But when I run `DIR /oe` the CLI doesn't show the folders with the custom .ico file - why would this be and is there a solution?

Comment: I gotcha now..  your saying that once RainbowFolders colourizes the folder, they no longer show up in a DIR via the CLI.  I just tested it myself, and it's true.  They seem to be hiding the folder and it's contents (you can still CD into them, and see the hidden files with Attrib).

Comment: Beware: while I was screwing around testing, somehow RainbowFolders managed to delete the content of the test folder (instead of just hiding it). :/

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - I'd be interested to know what caused the deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `/a` to your `dir` command; when you assign an icon to a folder, I believe it necessitates setting the 'system' flag on it, which `dir` hides by default.

e.g. `dir /a /oe`

Comment: Thanks very much Colin, works perfectly. Pity I can't vote up!